# Add a multi-line string to another string = lose multi-line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, concatenation, multiline

I wish to create a string that contains a list of stuff with one item on each line, but the following code doesn't maintain the new lines:

```
foreach (DateTime date in dates)
{
    datelist += date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + Environment.NewLine;
}

string mystring = String.Format(@"Hey there here is a list of dates

                                  Dates:

                                  {0}",
                                  datelist);
```

**Output:**

Hey there here is a list of dates

Dates:

2012/03/04 2012/03/05 2012/03/06

**Desired output:**

Hey there here is a list of dates

Dates:

2012/03/04

2012/03/05

2012/03/06

I tried variations, such as two Environment.NewLines, escapes like \r\n, starting the string with @, and so on, and I could not get my desired output.

I was ultimately able to solve my problem by putting a symbol into the string where I want linebreaks, and then use string.Replace to change the symbol to Environment.NewLine:

```
foreach (DateTime date in dates)
{
    datelist += date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "<br />";
}

string mystring = String.Format(@"Hey there here is a list of dates

                                  Dates:

                                  {0}",
                                  datelist.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
```

Like I said, this works, but I wish to know why good old concatenation doesn't work when inserting a string with lines into another string, as well as what the standard/common solution to my question would be.

Comment: are you outputting to HTML page?

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` is a newline character. If you're outputting to an HTML page (I can see you tagged asp.net in this question), that's clearly not going to work, since the page doesn't know what to do with a newline character. But that _is_ why your `<br />` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you render HTML output, you shouldn't use `Environment.NewLine` - use `<br />` instead. Multiple consecutive whitespace (including `\r` and `\n`) may be aggregated by the browser into a single whitespace. (Based on my experience, the actual behavior is somewhat browser dependent but I didn't actually research into this.)

```
foreach (DateTime date in dates)
{
    datelist += date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "<br />";
}

string mystring = String.Format("Hey there here is a list of dates<br />" +
    "Dates:<br />{0}", datelist);
```

If somewhere within the string you need multiple blank lines, use multiple `<br />`-s, of course.

Comment: Ahhh I came up with the idea to use String.Replace, but I had the order of the arguments mixed up in my mind --- I thought I was replacing <br /> with Environment.NewLine, but actually it's replacing Environment.NewLine with <br />, and I was thinking, "why does Environment.NewLine work here, but not in the original string?" --- now I'm just embarrassed :/  It's really not even necessary to use the Replace at all since I'm putting <br /> at the end of each concatenation.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt Lol, don't feel embarrased, it's the silly kind of oversight that happens to everyone. :)